# MYSQL: inserting data from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to insert data from two other tables. I currently have two tables, t1 and t2:

t1:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
 A     A     B     A     C
 B     B     C     C     A
 B     C     B     B     A
 C     A     A     A     B
```

and t2:

```
         A   B   C
col1     4   99  81
col2     50  26  38
col3     36  38  11
col4     16  49  70
col5     42  83  93
```

My goal is to form a new table which would simply use data from t1 and t2 and form a new table such as:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
 4     50    38    16    93
 99    26    11    70    42
 99    38    38    49    42
 81    50    36    16    83
```

I have been using CASE-function, but I've faced problems with attaching the tables. Any advices?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you solve the problem at programming language level?. Sometimes too much pressure is put on mysql.

Comment: It's defenitely solvable with the language I'm using (python), but mysql would be my first option.

Comment: Why do you need to store the data in a new table.  Why don't you just select the data you have?

Comment: Dan, I'd like to use the new table later and figured that it would be easier to form complete new table. Im a total sql-newbie and perhaps making an extra table is stupid. However any advice how to select data here? Thanks Dan and MboroMan for your replies!

Comment: I think this could be solved fairly easily with R.

Comment: looks like fun.  Can you redesign t1 so that it pivots the opposite way?  e.g. col1 | A | B | B | C

Comment: @jjjayn Please check, whether [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1382b/3/0) is of any use to you. I does return the expected result - but might be using constructs/approaches, which render it useless to you - missing your overall context. Basically, `t2` is considered a translation table, which has been transposed and given a bit of a life of its own in `t2t` for easier reference. (As long as this kind of hardcoding is feasible except for the view, one could, put the full view definition into each of the final query's five subselects. Similarly, the `dummy` is not absolutely necessary…)

Comment: I will comment again in the vein of the previous comment: why not creating your new table using your programming language? I remember phyton having some kind of dictionaries akin to std::maps or associative arrays in php or javascript crude objects... I would tend to think "do what's easiest for you, as you'll have to mantain in later!!". CASE statements in sql are really... peculiar. I haven't used one in a long long time. These days I only do basic retrieving and writing, leaving the bulk to the code itself :).

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan Sure - use the tool best suited to the job! -- Instead of asking a number of questions and checking a number of assumptions, I offered a route to travel, if certain conditions apply. Let's suppose: `t1`is the input - but keeps changing. `t2` describes the translation, and could easily be supplied in the transposed form (but OP just didn't think about that option) - voila: `dummy`and `t2t` no longer required. - You were done with a single SQL, still no `CASE`, no updates to a newly created table: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/628ed/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

If we convert `t2` from a wide table to a long table:

```
mysql> CREATE VIEW tidyt2 AS
       SELECT x as 'col', 'A' as 'label', A 'value' FROM t2
       UNION SELECT x as 'col', 'B' as 'label', B 'value' FROM t2
       UNION SELECT x as 'col', 'C' as 'label', C 'value' FROM t2;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from tidyt2;
+------+-------+-------+
| col  | label | value |
+------+-------+-------+
| col1 | A     |     4 |
| col2 | A     |    50 |
| col3 | A     |    36 |
| col4 | A     |    16 |
| col5 | A     |    42 |
| col1 | B     |    99 |
| col2 | B     |    26 |
| col3 | B     |    38 |
| col4 | B     |    49 |
| col5 | B     |    83 |
| col1 | C     |    81 |
| col2 | C     |    38 |
| col3 | C     |    11 |
| col4 | C     |    70 |
| col5 | C     |    93 |
+------+-------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then the desired table can be expressed using left joins:

```
mysql> SELECT t21.value as 'col1'
              , t22.value as 'col2'
              , t23.value as 'col3'
              , t24.value as 'col4'
              , t25.value as 'col5'
         FROM t1 
         LEFT JOIN tidyt2 as t21 ON t1.col1 = t21.label AND t21.col='col1'
         LEFT JOIN tidyt2 as t22 ON t1.col2 = t22.label AND t22.col='col2'
         LEFT JOIN tidyt2 as t23 ON t1.col3 = t23.label AND t23.col='col3'
         LEFT JOIN tidyt2 as t24 ON t1.col4 = t24.label AND t24.col='col4'
         LEFT JOIN tidyt2 as t25 ON t1.col5 = t25.label AND t25.col='col5';

+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    4 |   50 |   38 |   16 |   93 |
|   99 |   26 |   11 |   70 |   42 |
|   99 |   38 |   38 |   49 |   42 |
|   81 |   50 |   36 |   16 |   83 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```